# Calling the same endpoint with multiple requests

Tags: api, request, nestjs, endpoint

I'm in the process of deprecating an old API and want two (or multiple) requests to call the same endpoint. Something like this:

```
@Get('/request')      // call endpoint with this request
@Get('/otherRequest') // or with this request
test() {
  // do something
}
```

Clearly another way to do this would be to create another endpoint and use a service to share the functionality, but I am curious if this is possible as it would make the process easier to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
@Get(['/request', '/otherRequest'])
test() {
  // do something
}
```

tip: inspect the TS types of `@Get()` ^^